# insert special character on SQLite with FMDB

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I have an issue with inserting a value into table by FMDB.
I have SQL string like this:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO table( COMPANY, PAGE_NO ) VALUES ('%@',%d,%d)",value1,value2,value3];
```

And I use FMDB like this for SQL string above:

```
[FMDatabase: 0x433e80> executeUpdate: sql]
```

It works, but when I use `value1 = @"Test'12"`. It has a character `" ' "` and it fails.

Please help me, I want to keep using the method `executeUpdate` from FMDB

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're not passing the correct number of parameters to your query, you're listing 2 columns and passing 3 parameters. I'll assume that's a typo.

You should really parameterise your query; use `?` where the parameters should go and instead pass them to `executeUpdate`. That way, problematic characters will be handled automatically.

That would change your code to something more like;

```
NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO table(COMPANY, PAGE_NO) VALUES (?,?)";
[database executeUpdate:sql, value1, [NSNumber numberWithInt:value2], nil];
```

Note the call to `numberWithInt` that is required to convert `int` to an `NSNumber`, since `executeUpdate` requires all its arguments to be objects, not primitive types.